# How to make a pointer increment by 1 byte, not 1 unit

Tags: c, pointers, increment

I have a structure `tcp_option_t`, which is `N` bytes. If I have a pointer `tcp_option_t* opt`, and I want it to be incremented by 1, I can't use `opt++` or `++opt` as this will increment by `sizeof(tcp_option_t)`, which is `N`.

I want to move this pointer by 1 byte only. My current solution is

```
opt = (tcp_option_t *)((char*)opt+1);
```

but it is a bit troublesome. Are there any better ways?

Comment: That's probably the only solution.

Comment: You really don't want to do that...or, perhaps, why on earth do you think you want to do that (because you really don't want to do that!)?

Comment: No, that's exactly the right way to do it. But why would you want to?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd suggest you to create a pointer of char and use it to transverse your struct.

```
char *ptr = (char*) opt;
++ptr; // will increment by one byte
```

when you need to restore your struct again, from ptr, just do the usual cast:

```
opt = (tcp_option_t *) ptr;
```

Comment: That won't work at all if `ptr` has been incremented by less than `sizeof tcp_option_t `.

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is very old, but I had the same question and found this solution:

```
char **ptr = (char**) &opt;
++(*ptr); // will increment opt by one byte
```

No need to restore the struct.

This is working on Visual Studio 2005. I hope it works with all compiler.

Comment: Sorry, but what does this answer add to the already given one (except unnecessary asterisks and confusion?)